# Status of snapshots.ros.org

Tags: docker, apt

I am using [snapshots.ros.org](https://snapshots.ros.org) as my apt mirror for my Humble docker image and wanted to update to the latest humble release. From the [ROS discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-ros-2-humble-hawksbill-2022-11-01/28085) page, we should see a 2022-11-01 release in the snapshot mirror. The [latest](http://snapshots.ros.org/humble/) I see is 2023-07-24. Is there plans to update the mirror to include newer Humble releases?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both the `Noetic` and `Humble` distros received a new snapshot yesterday (10-10-23).